# Selecting a class method name using Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, linq, reflection, lambda

Currently in my code I have a method like this:

```
.AddMethod(nameof(IRoleService.GetRoles))
```

What Im trying to do is selecting the interface method using lambda expression and then get the name of method inside AddMethod. 
So the result would be :

```
.AddMethod<IRoleService>(x=> x.GetRoles)
```

I have tried this:

```
AddMethod<T>(Expression<Func<T, Action>> expression);
```

But the problem is some of the interface methods have input parameters which I'm trying to ignore, as I just need the method name. 
Would be thankful if you help me with this.

Alex

Comment: How does the new selected answer fixes your issue? It may work with an `Action` (no input parameters) but what happens if some method has input parameters as you stated in your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved with a little bit of digging into the `LambdaExpression` like this:

```
string GetMethodCallName(LambdaExpression expression)
{
    var unary = (UnaryExpression)expression.Body;
    var methodCall = (MethodCallExpression)unary.Operand;
    var constant = (ConstantExpression)methodCall.Object;
    var memberInfo = (MemberInfo)constant.Value;

    return memberInfo.Name;
}
```

Unfortunately `GetMethodCallName` cannot be called directly with the `x => x.GetRoles` syntax you want since there is no type argument to define what `x` is. This means you'll need to create an overload of `AddMethod` for every number of input arguments you want to support for both `Action` and `Func`:

```
void AddMethod<T>(Expression<Func<T, Action>> expression);
void AddMethod<T, Arg1>(Expression<Func<T, Action<Arg1>>> expression);
void AddMethod<T, Arg1, Arg2>(Expression<Func<T, Action<Arg1, Arg2>>> expression);

void AddMethod<T, TResult>(Expression<Func<T, Func<TResult>>> expression);
void AddMethod<T, Arg1, TResult>(Expression<Func<T, Func<Arg1, TResult>>> expression);
void AddMethod<T, Arg1, Arg2, TResult>(Expression<Func<T, Func<Arg1, Arg2, TResult>>> expression);
```

Then in each `AddMethod` implementation call `GetMethodCallName` with the expression argument:

```
void AddMethod<T, Arg1>(Expression<Func<T, Action<Arg1>>> expression)
{
    var methodName = GetMethodCallName(expression);
}
```

Then you can call `AddMethod` and specify the containing type and the return and input types of the method:

```
.AddMethod<IRoleService>(x => x.GetRoles);
.AddMethod<IRoleService, TResult>(x => x.GetRoles);
.AddMethod<IRoleService, Arg1, TResult>(x => x.GetRoles);
```

Where:

- `TResult` is the return type of `.GetRoles`
- `Arg1` is the type of the first argument of `.GetRoles`

Comment: How does this answer solves the issue? OP said: **But the problem is some of the interface methods have input parameters which I'm trying to ignore, as I just need the method name. Would be thankful if you help me with this.**

Comment: I updated my solution to cater for input parameters. Sadly there is no way around specifying the types of the input parameters, but at least no value needs to be provided.

Comment: Hacky but works, it's better to write 20 overloads once, and then have easy use 100+ times

Answer (score 3):

> But the problem is some of the interface methods have input parameters
>   which I'm trying to ignore

You can't *ignore* input parameters unless these parameters have default values.

If you can't change your code to set default values to these methods' input parameters, you'll need to provide default values yourself using reflection to get the so-called input parameters and give them some values. Or you can just give them during compile-time:

```
// I don't know which parameters accept your methods...
AddMethod<IRoleService>(x => x.GetRoles("arg1", 2));
```

#### OP said...

> considering I just need the Method Name, Do you suggest a clean way to
>   get the name without passing parameters?

There's no dirty or clean way of doing so. Expression trees are still *valid* code (i.e. it should be code that can be built into executable code).

How you would produce an expression tree where you access a method name instead of calling it? Or how you access a method to call it without parameters if the whole method has parameters? Would be this valid C# code? The answer is ***no***.

Comment: Thanks @Matías Fidemraizer.

Comment: considering I just need the Method Name, Do you suggest a clean way to get the name without passing parameters?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed description. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @Alex You're welcome. Well, sometimes an answer is to say *there's no solution to your issue*... ;)